# Can I boot my NAS from another computer?

Tags: boot, nas, freenas

I am currently running a HP N40L with FreeNAS.  Is there a way to boot up over the network without physically turning it on?  It's lazy I know but let's just say I'm a fan of automation where ever possible, after all that's what computers are for!

**EDIT:**

Following the Wake On Lan suggestions here is a [quick and easy way to do it from the dos command line.](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cmd.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use Wake on Lan (WoL) to do it. I've never used WoL, but there are help articles out there. (note that your NAS must first be capable of WoL!)

Here's a couple of articles to get you started. If you need any further help, leave a comment
Good luck!

[lifehacker WoL](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan)
[smallnetbuilder HowTo: WoL](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-howto/29941-how-to-wake-on-lan-wake-on-wan)

Answer (score 1):

Wake on Lan is a good solution, as pointed out by @Sylvester. If you want even more remote control then HP offers a Remote Access Card for the N40L Microserver. It is an add-in card that allows you to access the server through a browser or SSH and allows you to power up/down, enter the BIOS and even boot the server using an image on your client, mounted as a virtual floppy disk, CD or DVD.

See the [User Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02948881.pdf) (5MB PDF) for details.